# Setting state of javascript function not saving

Tags: javascript, namespaces, closures

I am trying to create a new function, MyNs.MyObj(), call a method on it that modifies a 'private' variable, 'prop1', and the next time I access the public accessor, 'Prop1' that it retrieves the saved variable.

After running the below code, the output is still, '2' (the initial value).  Can someone help me understand why calling the Method function does not udpate the Prop1 variable the way I expect?

```
var MyNs = MyNs || {};

(function( o ){
    o.MyObj = function (options) {
        var prop1 = options;

        var obj = {
            Prop1: prop1,
            Method: function() { 
                prop1 = "abc";
            }
        };

        return obj;
    };
})(MyNs);

var s = new MyNs.MyObj(2);
s.Method();

console.log(s.Prop1);
```

Comment: You're not referencing what you think you are, inside `Method` you have to use `this.Prop1` to change that property, now you're just creating a new global.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do this

```
var prop1 = options;

var obj = {
    Prop1: prop1
};
```

You've set `Prop1` to the value of `prop1` at that time, changing `prop1` later will not update `Prop1`.
You can easily test this with something like

```
var a = 'abc'; // set a value on 'a'
var b = a;     // set 'b' to equal 'a', as it's a string, it's passed directly

a = 'bca';     // set a new value for 'a'

alert(b);      // still outputs 'abc'
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/CMyUW/)

This means you have to update the property, not the variable, and you'd do that like so

```
var MyNs = MyNs || {};

(function( o ){
    o.MyObj = function (options) {
        var prop1 = options;

        var obj = {
            Prop1: prop1,
            Method: function() { 
                this.Prop1 = "abc";
            }
        };

        return obj;
    };
})(MyNs);

var s = new MyNs.MyObj(2);
s.Method();

console.log(s.Prop1);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Nh8Mq/2/)